# Submitting a form on a live webpage with PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm trying to find a way for PHP to press the "submit" button on a PHP form on a live webpage.

I need to do this as I am unsure as towards what data is send through this form, as it is a post form and the API is closed source.

Is there anyway to send a jQuery like click command to a live webpage through PHP at all?

Nothing needs to be retrieved from this form, only needs to have pressed the button correctly.

**EDIT**

More context:

Yes, the site is 3rd party (this is why I can't simply look up something on any  API documentation), the program is downloading a gallery of images through the in-site gallery archiver. Previously the URL for this gallery's archive was stored on a simple popup window page's source. Now however you must confirm it first the page reloads (after a form submits through POST) onto the same page (archiver.php) and the download starts. This reloaded page contains the URL of the file. Nothing is submitted beyond the users confirmation to the download manually, perhaps something in the back end is sent upon this, I don't know.

**EDIT 2**

I've fixed this by figuring out what the form submits.

Comment: Repaeat after me: "PHP is server-side, JavaScript is client-side....mostly."

Comment: Do you own the page in question, or are you (i suspect) talking about interacting with a 3rd party web page

Comment: Will a user submi this form, for example: name, email, comment - > submit

Comment: I've added some more context to the main post

Comment: no you cant click button with php. You would need to simulate the form post request instead. You can use network tools in your browser to work out what data you need to send, then use curl to make the request. Do you have a link to the page in question?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible to click a button on another page with php or jquery.

But you can analyse the form and find out the destination URL and send a own request. If it is GET it should look like this: myhomepage.com?id=1&name=foo&password=hello123

Answer (score 0):

you have  to use jQuery or javaScript For pressing submit button on live page dynamically. PHP is server side script and from is client side  so its not possible. but if you want to read data from live webpage  than you have to use cURL or file_get content